# Django: re-use login_required decorator inside other decorators

Tags: django, decorator, login-required

According to one of the comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8715790/210481, which I agree with, we should avoid multiple decorators if one depends on the other.

So, in the example, if we have a decorator "active_required" for active users, we should not have to use both active_required and login_required on the same view.

We should have "login_required" decorator "called" somehow inside the "active_required" one.

Is it possible to do it with the standard "login_required" decorator that comes with django?

My requirements are:
1) if the user is not authenticated, I should redirect him to LOGIN_URL
2) if the user is authenticated (passed login_required), but is not active, I should redirect him to a page to "re-activate" his account
3) if the user is authenticated and active, the user can access the view

Thanks in advance

Comment: since you want different behaviours in the 3 possible cases, having two decorators seems fine

Comment: As I understard you want to use only one decorator instead of two that does two different tests?

Comment: I want 2 different behaviors but one depends necessarily on the other.
@ChrisPratt, I was looking at your comment, when I thought of this. The standard login function does not check for "active" flag, only if username and password match. I can think of other examples: In my site, users can create lists and only the owner of the list can edit the list, so I need to check if the user is logged in and if it's the owner of the list. This is just another example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When thinking about your question, I found it easier to create a simple `active_required` decorator first. This is very easy, because we can use the the `user_passes_test` function in `django.contrib.auth.decorators`.

The question then changes to "how do I combine the `login_required` and `active_required` into one decorator?". We need to define a function which:

1. takes a view function as it's argument
2. applies both decorators to it to create a new view function
3. returns the new view function

Putting it all together, you have the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test, login_required

active_required = user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_active, login_url=REACTIVATE_URL)

def active_and_login_required(view_func):
    decorated_view_func = login_required(active_required(view_func))
    return decorated_view_func
```