# Cannot access API view on post request using decorator [AllowAny]

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I have a simple function-based `@api_view(['POST'])` with `@permission_classes([AllowAny])`
and DRF settings in settings.py are:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

The [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) says:

> The AllowAny permission class will allow unrestricted access,
> regardless of if the request was authenticated or unauthenticated.

But I'm getting the following response on making a post request:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

What might be the problem? Do I have to modify `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` from the settings? I don't want the permissions to be required while making the request on this `@api_view`:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny]) 
def reset_password_request(email):
    try:
    #...
```

accounts/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<str:pk>/', views.getUserById, name='user'),
    path('user/password_reset_request/',
         views.resetPasswordRequest, name='password_reset_request'),
]
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241871/discussion-between-faisal-nazik-and-aaron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` is not specified, it defaults to allowing unrestricted access.

The problem is in your URL patterns, where `password_reset_request` satisfies `<str:pk>` and `getUserById` with `@permission_classes([...])` is called instead.

Either use the `uuid` path converter:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # path('user/<str:pk>/', views.getUserById, name='user'),  # Change this
    path('user/<uuid:pk>/', views.getUserById, name='user'),   # to this
    path('user/password_reset_request/',
         views.resetPasswordRequest, name='password_reset_request'),
]
```

Or reorder to match `password_reset_request` first:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # path('user/<str:pk>/', views.getUserById, name='user'),  # Move this
    path('user/password_reset_request/',
         views.resetPasswordRequest, name='password_reset_request'),
    path('user/<str:pk>/', views.getUserById, name='user'),    # to here
]
```

References:

- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the issue, You were right the issue was in the URLs. Thanks for the answer again,

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8715821/11282077), the position of decorator is wrong. The first decorator to be executed should be on the top. Change your decorator to the bottom like this:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def reset_password_request(email):
    try:
    #...
```

Check out the [official documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy) for reference.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, the same thing happened, is there any issue from `'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'`, Can we swap this and same time use JWT.

Comment: As far as I know AllowAny is regarding the permission classes. It has nothing to do with the authentication classes. It has to work for either user is authenticated or not. I am not sure. Please check once again if there is something (jwt middleware or drf) in settings.py that is restricting this

Answer (score 0):

Let's work through it step by step: Add `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` as follows (for troubleshooting):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
     )
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

** **EDIT 1** **

Try adding `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` as follows:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
     )
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

** **EDIT 2** **

Now that you have a [`403`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication), modify the default to `rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny` as shown below. If this works, remove the `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` and use decorators instead.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
     )
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

Comment: Doing this undermines other classes , Like DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS , like http://localhost:8000/api/v1/docs/ Here anyone can access the docs of the API but now this also says `Authentication credentials were not provided.` on this endpoint.

Comment: previously it was giving an error with status code 401 means forbidden like in my original settings, but now giving 403 meaning unauthorized, but not allowing the request.

Comment: Have you been able to test the latest edit? How did it work for you?

Comment: Yes. Same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241868/discussion-between-faisal-nazik-and-scriptcode).